# Coded UI Unable to locate controls in expanded rows

Tags: c#, wpf, coded-ui-tests

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755252/coded-ui-test-finding-controls-on-expanded-row), I'm trying to develop a Coded UI test which needs to perform a few assertions on some controls which are located in a WPF row (row details). The Coded UI inspector unfortunately doesn't appear to be able to locate any of the controls in the expanded row as it identifies those controls as being children of a custom control (Uia.DataGridDetailsPresenter) which is a child of the row.

The application's xaml for this grid is pretty straight forward as displayed below.

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}" Margin="10" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Has anyone managed to access the row details using in a Coded UI test before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing this issue by writing my own DataGrid control which exposed the desired automation peer.

Generic automation peer

```
class GenericAutomationPeer : UIElementAutomationPeer
{
    public GenericAutomationPeer(UIElement owner)
        : base(owner)
    {

    }

    protected override List<AutomationPeer> GetChildrenCore()
    {
        List<AutomationPeer> list = base.GetChildrenCore();
        list.AddRange(GetChildPeers(Owner));
        return list;
    }

    private List<AutomationPeer> GetChildPeers(UIElement element)
    {
        List<AutomationPeer> automationPeerList = new List<AutomationPeer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
        {
            UIElement child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as UIElement;
            if (child != null)
            {
                AutomationPeer childPeer = UIElementAutomationPeer.CreatePeerForElement(child);
                if (childPeer != null)
                {
                    automationPeerList.Add(childPeer);
                }
                else
                {
                    automationPeerList.AddRange(GetChildPeers(child));
                }
            }
        }

        return automationPeerList;
    }
}
```

Custom DataGrid

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    //Override automation peer that the base class provides as it doesn't expose automation peers for the row details
    protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        return new GenericAutomationPeer(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, Coded UI inspector sees Uia.DataGridDetailsPresenter and it's children, but can't work with them during test run.

Well, there is probably problem with your app, this DataGrid is not published for coded ui automation. I had the same problem with TabPage content too.

If you want to know, what Coded UI sees in Wpf application execute this code, you will get some elements map in output - copy to excel. If this finds controls you need, your tests should find them too.

```
    /*
     *  Method used for get map of element and it's children
     *  element - element whose children you want to explore
     *  comma - use empty string - ""
    */

    public void getMap(WpfControl element, String comma)
    {
        comma = comma + "\t";

        foreach (Object child in element.GetChildren())
        {
            WpfControl childAsWpf = child as WpfControl;
            if (childAsWpf != null && !(element is WpfListItem))
            {
                logElementInfo(childAsWpf, comma);
                getMap(childAsWpf, comma);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("--------- object: {0}; type: {1}", child, child.GetType());
            }
        }
    }

    // logs element info in Output
    private void logElementInfo(WpfControl element, String comma)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}AutomationId: {1}, ClassName: {2}, ControlType: Wpf{3}", comma, element.AutomationId, element.ClassName, element.ControlType);
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't solve the current issue but it certainly has helped exposed a few controls that we'll be needing to fix in the future. We ran into the same issue with TabPages but managed to solve it by stitching the control's container to the parent view.

Comment: This can't solve your issue. It only shows you where the problem is (tests or app).